# How to get json Array not html from URL in android

Tags: php, android, json, android-volley

I am trying to get json Array from url in android using volley but it is showing following error

com.android.volley.ParseError: org.json.JSONException: Value  of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray

that means i am receiving html from url.

how can i receive data in json format from url so that i can parse using jsonObject or jsonArray in android

My android code is

```
 RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());

 JsonArrayRequest  request = new JsonArrayRequest(Method.GET, URL,null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {


     @Override
     public void onResponse(JSONArray response ) {


         Toast.makeText(getContext(), response, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

         Log.i("My success",""+response.toString());
            try {
                    for (int i = 0; i <= response.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject silver_rate_values = response.getJSONObject(i);
                    String Silver_Rate = silver_rate_values.getString("silver_rate");
                    Log.v("SilverRate", "silverRate value is" + Silver_Rate);
                }
            }catch (JSONException e) {
                     e.printStackTrace();
                     Log.e("Silver rate", "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                 }

            }

     }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

     @Override

     public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {


         Toast.makeText(getContext(), "my error :"+error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

         Log.i("My error",""+error);

     }

 }){


 };
```

---

---

---

My php code is

```
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `user_info`  \n"

. "ORDER BY `customer_info`.`updatedTime`  DESC LIMIT 1";


   $result = mysqli_query(  $con,$sql );


   if(! $result ) {
       
   die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());

     }



   //print values to screen
   $data = array();
   while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   $a = $row['a'];
   $b = $row['b'];
   $c =  $row['c'];
   $data[] = $row;


    }
   header('Content-type: application/json');
  

   $json=json_encode(array("Values" => $data));

   echo $json;

   ?>
</body>
```

My php output is

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
    {"Values":[{"a":"8888","b":"9999","c"7777"}]}   </body>
    </html>
```

If I remove header from php code then the output is
{"Values":[{"a":"8888","b":"9999","c"7777"}]}

Then  also I am getting same error from Android side

Comment: Delete all of the HTML out of the page that echos the JSON.

Comment: Your php output contains html tags. It must only contain data in JSON format.

Comment: @Mrudul... I have tried that also.. But still the same error..

Answer (score 0):

**just Add this line you can achive result**

```
$jsonfinal = json_encode(json_decode($json), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
       echo $jsonfinal ;
```

Comment: It will ultimately give the same result... What is its use

Comment: yes it will give the same result .I realize this question is asking about how to encode an associative array to a pretty-formatted JSON string, so this doesn't directly answer the question, but if you have a string that is already in JSON format, you can make it pretty simply by decoding and re-encoding it (requires PHP >= 5.4):

Comment: Question is not about to encode an associative array to a pretty-formatted JSON string... That part is done.... Problem is when I am sending this Json to Android... Android is  receiving html data not Json one..... As you can see the error..

Comment: if you have used json pretty in your code it wont return html tags in android. If you are still having an issue kindly share your response too.

Comment: while running the above code....error listener gets called..not response (error is mentioned)

Answer (score 0):

now i am changing my code and using StringRequest instead of  JsonArrayRequest. below is the code

```
     RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());

 StringRequest  request = new StringRequest(Method.GET, URL_Silver, new Response.Listener<String>() {


     @Override
     public void onResponse(String response ) {


          Log.i("My success",""+response);
            try {
                
                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);
                JSONArray array = obj.getJSONArray("silverRateValues");

                for (int i = 0; i <= array.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject silver_rate_values = array.getJSONObject(i);
                    String Silver_Rate = silver_rate_values.getString("silver_rate");
                    Log.v("SilverRate", "silverRate value is" + Silver_Rate);
                }
            }catch (JSONException e) {
                     e.printStackTrace();
                     Log.e("Silver rate", "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                 }

            }

     }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

     @Override

     public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {


         Toast.makeText(getContext(), "my error :"+error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

         Log.i("My error",""+error);

     }

 }){


 };


 queue.add(request);
```

But still getting the same error...however now response is called and it is...

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
    {"Values":[{"a":"8888","b":"9999","c":"7777"}]} </body>
    </html>
```

and the error is

org.json.JSONException: Value  of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject